# JPA: check whether an entity object has been persisted or not

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

Is there a general method that can

```
 if(entity is persisted before){
     entity = entity.merge();
 }else{
     entity.persist();
 }
```

So the method contain above logic is safe everywhere?

Comment: Why do you need it? `merge()` already performs this check.

Comment: @axtavt Thanks. So if the entity never persisted, then `merge()` will persist the entity? Otherwise merge the entity and return a merged copy?

Comment: Yes, but for transient object it returns persisted copy as well rather than persists original object.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you need to know is object already in persistence context you should use `contains` method of `EntityManager`.

Only `EntityManager` can tell you is entity persisted or not, entity does not have such information.

Here you can check javadoc for [`contains` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29).

```
if (!em.contains(entity)) {
  em.persist(entity);
} else {
  em.merge(entity);
}
```

Comment: sure, this should be if (!em.contains(entity)) ? Otherwise, you are persisting an entity that is already "contained" within the em...

Comment: if the persisted entity is detached, this method will not work.

Comment: As stated by @Sunnyday , this answer is misleading. Per JPA specification, the `contains(..)` method of `EntityManager` is not defined as a lookup method for the actual DB state of an `Entity`, but as a lookup within a persistence context. Further clarification is found in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49114622/2849346

Answer (score 4):

To check if entity object has been persisted or not by the current PersistenceContext you can use the EntityManager method [contains(Object entity)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's too late, but here are my findings!
If you have an entity with a generate value, you can use it to check if the entity is already in DB, assuming you are not modifying this value manually.

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
   
    // getter...
}

public class Main {
    public static void main() {
        MyEntity myEntity1 = new MyEntity();
        MyEntity myEntity2 = em.find(MyEntity.class, 4);
        em.detach(myEntity2); // or em.close()

        // other stuff and modifications

        // begin transaction
        persistEntity(myEntity1); // will use persist()
        persistEntity(myEntity2); // will use merge()
        // commit transaction

    }

    // This will manage correctly entities in different state
    public void persistEntity(MyEtity entity) {
        if (myEntity.getId() != null) em.merge(entity);
        else em.persist(entity);
    }
}
```

Using **em.contains(entity)** will fail in this scenario:

```
public static void main(){
    MyEntity myEntity = em.find(MyEntity.class, 5);
    
    em.detach(myEntity); // or em.close()
  
    // We are going to execute persist() because the entity is detached
    if (!em.contains(myEntity)) 
        // This call will produce an exception org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException
        em.persist(myEntity);
    else 
        em.merge(myEntity);
}
```

There are a performance reasons to try to achieve what OP is trying to do. You surely can use **em.merge()** instead of **em.persist()**, but not without a cost.

A call to **em.merge()** is trying to retrieve an existing entity from DB with a *SELECT* query and update it. So if the entity was never persisted, this will waste some CPU cycles. On the other side **em.persist()** will only produce one *INSERT* query.