# Why does 'EntityManager.contains(..)' return false even if an entity is contained in DB?

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager, jpa-2.1

I used this [JPA: check whether an entity object has been persisted or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092008/jpa-check-whether-an-entity-object-has-been-persisted-or-not/16092231#16092231)
 to know if i persist or merge my entity , It will look like this :

```
if (!getEntityManager().contains(entity)) {
        System.out.println(" PERSIST ");            
    } else {
        System.out.println(" MERGE ");
    }
```

The case is that - even if I edit my entity - it will not recognized as a merge.

How is it possible and how to make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [JPA 2.1 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf) (PDF page 72),

the `EntityManager` method `public boolean contains(Object entity)` does:

> Check if the instance is a managed entity instance belonging to the current *persistence context*.

For this reason, the check is not conducted against the actual database, but against the current *[persistence context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930152/what-is-persistence-context)*.

Moreover, on PDF page 86 of the spec document we find:

> The `contains` method returns `true`:
>
> • If the entity has been retrieved from the database or has been returned by getReference, and has **not** been removed or **detached**.
>
> • If the entity instance is new, and the persist method has been called on the entity or the persist operation has been cascaded to it.
>
> The `contains` method returns `false`:
>
> • If the instance is **detached**.

Most likely, you have a **detached** entity state in the moment the calling code of the code snippet is executed. Thus, the call for `contains(..)` always evaluates to `false`.

As an alternative, you can use

- `public <T> T find(Class<T> entityClass, Object primaryKey)` (see p. 66) *or*
- `public <T> T getReference(Class<T> entityClass, Object primaryKey)` (see p. 68)

to check the presence as a tuple in the underlying database. Which one of the above methods you chose will depend on the context of your code/application.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i think it will be completed if you add an example (how to use it) about the two alternative answers it will be the greatest answer ever.

Comment: I found ever a better solution are you interested to improve your answer to make it a better one ?!?

Comment: read the answer with one upvote (it was me ) (How to get the primary key of any JPA entity?
)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328813/how-to-get-the-primary-key-of-any-jpa-entity/46073932#46073932]

Comment: This might be specific to certain Persistence providers only, such as Hibernate or Eclipselink and might not work in pure JPA style. Will check on this during the next days. And I think: Maybe, this is beyond the scope of the original question about `contains(..)`.

Comment: Yes i totally agree with you but the answer that i provided to you can used instead of `contains(..)` as an alternative solution